# Installing CUDA without replacing DisplayDriver

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nvidia

I was just wondering if it would be possible to install the CUDA toolkit without replacing my Display Driver. I don't mind the other changes that the installation would make to my system, but wish to keep my current NVIDIA display driver, rather than change to the one in the CUDA installation. Therefore, is this possible, or is the replacement display driver required to develop and run cuda programmes?

Comment: Note that profiling may not work properly when display driver version is not the same as this which is included in CUDA Toolkit. See https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/630905/nsight-visual-studio-edition/-quot-profile-cuda-application-quot-always-fails-with-quot-no-kernel-launches-captured-quot-/

Comment: Profiling *should* work.  Driver bugs are always possible, but it's never the design intent that you should have to use an older driver to achieve some functionality (such as profiling).  Just as the poster in the linked article solved their problem by rolling back to an older driver, they might just as easily have solved it by moving forward to a newer driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a display driver that is at least as recent as that included in the CUDA toolkit that you are installing.    For example, Linux CUDA 5.5 requires a 319.37 or newer display driver, Linux CUDA 5.0 requires a 304.54 or newer display driver.

During the install of the toolkit, you will be prompted as to which components you want to install (driver, toolkit, samples).  You can select `no` when prompted for the driver, if you wish to keep your driver.  There are [getting started guides](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#getting-started-guides) for each of the supported platforms (windows, linux, mac).

Comment: Hello. Well, I keep the driver's updated through GEFORCE EXPERIENCE, so they should be up to date.